# How to display data from one View to another ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

If I have for example model `Ticket.cs` which contain following field

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme")]
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }
```

And in `Index.cshtml` I display this data.
Another Model Discussion.cs

```
public class Discussion
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }        

        [Display(Name = "Odgovor")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
      
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    }
```

Right now, I want data from Ticket.cs transfer to Discussion Index.cshtml  to be display like

`DateTime`,`Description`

What Do I need to do in my controller to get this kind of data exactly same as it is in `Ticket model`
Please let me know if you need more information or source code. I didn't put much code in order to post be more clear.
Is the best way to pass to my `Discussion Model`

```
public Ticket ticket {get;set;}
```

Or create ViewModel

**UPDATE**

Once I include in my View

```
@model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.DiscussionTicketVM
```

And when I use `foreach look`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item</td>
                        <td>08/14/2017</td>
                        <td>nn</td>
                        <td>nn</td>
                        <td>Website problem</td>
                        <td><span class="text-primary">Open</span></td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I get error message

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DiscussionTicketVM' because 'DiscussionTicketVM' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, you should use the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` is a combination of several models that are displayed in one view.

Suppose you have a view in which both customer information and product information must be displayed. To do this, you need to create a class and create an instance of each model that appears in the view.

```
public class DiscussionTicketViewModel
{
    public Discussion discussion { get; set; }
    public Ticket ticket { get; set; }
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new DiscussionTicketViewModel();
    model.ticket = //.............
    model.discussion = //.........
    return View(model);
}
```

In View

```
<tr>
  <td>@Model.ticket.Description</td>
  <td>08/14/2017</td>
  <td>nn</td>
  <td>nn</td>
  <td>Website problem</td>
  <td><span class="text-primary">Open</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you :) One more question 
`model.ticket = //.............` what does this mean ?

Comment: I get error message. I update my question

Comment: I cannot acces ticket. It throw error in foreach look 
`@foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`